# Не проходить через тесты с налогами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу решить задачу 293 на Acmp про налоги, вот ссылка: https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=293 , так вот написал код но на четвертым тесте пишит что не правильно, помогите что не так с кодом:

```
n = int(input())
V = list(map(int,input().split()))
p = list(map(int,input().split()))
m =[]

for i in range(n):
  if p[i] == 0:
    m.append(p[i])
    continue
  else:
    m.append(V[i]/p[i]*100)
    
print(m.index(max(m))+1)
```

и обьясните где я был не прав... за ранее спасибо

Comment: "но на четвертым тесте " - что такое 4й тест? Просьба его ясно написать. По ссылке я, например, N1,2,3 вижу

Comment: это так можно объяснить, мне дано задача написать программу которая должна что-то делать по условию и она должна решить все тесты (в моем случае их 40). Первые три теста показаны на сайти надо написать программу которая проходить все тесты

Comment: ясно, то есть мы этот тест не увидим:-) Надо просто исправить скрипт, а Аянат сам тестировать будет:-)

Comment: И не ясно, зачем continue тут, кстати. Ничего не портит, но просто не нужно, на мой взгляд.

Comment: тогда что нужно поставить?

Comment: Ничего не надо. if- else работает по приципу "или-или". После  m.append(p[i]) ничего больше не выполнится, а итерация и так перейдет на следующий шаг (i увеличится), а continue для этого и нужен (прервать выполнение, увеличить i). Рекомендую перечитать про условие if-elif-else а также логику continue и  break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала предлагаю исправить:

```
m.append(V[i]*p[i])
```

Общий объем налога - процент умноженный на объем. По определению того, что такое процент.

Comment: сам вот только что нашел свою ошибку, все равно спасибо. m.append(V[i]*p[i]/100) вот так будет даже правильнее

Comment: А, это да, верно. Я не обратил внимания, что проценты целые, а не в сотых.